# Is it possible to establish a permanent linkage between a file and its executable?

Tags: file, executable, linkage

I've been digging around looking for the answer but I failed. The question is.. 
Is it really possible to create a permanent static connection between a file and its application so that when you run the application, the file is already loaded without having to open the file from the menu or drag and drop it to the application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible because it is the same approach used by Qt resources

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

How this is achieved behind the scene, I guess it's a bit complicated

Concerning the Java world,  you'd put the file in the jar file of your application,  but that's not really a binding at binary level,  but more putting everything inside an archive

Comment: I could barely make head of the represented link because I've got no coding knowledge but it seem like the way to do it. I have a friend who knows a couple of languages. maybe he could help me with it. for the time being, isn't there an easy to do method or a step by step guide for Windows applications ?

Comment: The problem is that there is no standard way to do such thing. I think I got what you meant before. You basically want to bind a file to an application which doesn't provide such feature. In this case I think it's not possible, but maybe some Windows expert could say that I is

Comment: Ok... I guess the given link is the best answer. thanks